# How to tell if a sqlite table view is empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I have a working RSS feed reader using SQLite 3 for the iPhone that I have submitted to apple for review. What I am wandering is wether is there a way to tell if a sqlite table view is empty. I have read about doing this, but I can't seem to find one for using SQLite. I want this because when the user first opens the app, the item view controller is empty until they refresh the table by pulling down. Is there a way to add a label that says something like, "Please refresh", but only when the table is empty?

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from some_table;
```

If that returns 0 then the table is empty. Of course if you already have a query against a table that returns all rows and you get back zero rows then you know the table is empty.

If you know there is an empty table then setup your table view's data source with 1 row that displays your "please refresh" message.

But if there is no data, what is the point of refreshing? And if the user can refresh, then why not do it automatically for the user? Why make the user do the refresh?

Answer (score 0):

On your viewDidLoad method, you must get all the feed from sqlite... so start a loading view on viewDidLoad.. and remove that view when you get all the views.... then you could check your  list of items for count and when the count == 0, display what ever message you want to display.